WordPress Plugin Text Domain Not Loading for Translations
I am developing a custom WordPress plugin called netpeak-seo and I'm encountering issues with loading the text domain for translations. Despite following the correct structure and ensuring that the .mo and .po files are in the right directory, the text domain doesn’t seem to load properly in the admin interface.
Plugin Structure:
https://img.netpeak.net/masik/home/2024-10-06_pRoSs.png
Issue:
I have included the following function in my init.php file to load the text domain:
function netpeak_seo_load_textdomain() {
load_plugin_textdomain( 'netpeak-seo', false, plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'languages' );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'netpeak_seo_load_textdomain' );

However, when I check if the text domain is loaded using is_textdomain_loaded(), I receive a message indicating that the text domain is not loaded. Additionally, translations that should be displayed in the admin interface do not show up.
I have verified that:

The .mo and .po files are in the correct languages/ folder.
The text domain netpeak-seo is consistently used across the plugin, both in functions like __(), 3. _e(), and _x(), as well as in the translation files.
The plugin's language settings in WordPress are set to Bulgarian (bg_BG).
The path for the translation files seems correct.

Debugging Attempts:
I added a file_exists() check to verify that the .mo file is found in the correct path, and the file is indeed found.
I also tried changing the action hook from plugins_loaded to init, but the issue persists.
I've cleared the cache and checked other potential conflicts, but nothing seems to resolve the problem.
What could be causing the text domain not to load in this case? Is there something I'm missing in terms of how WordPress handles plugin localization? Any advice or guidance would be appreciated.
